# Getting parameter from request path in Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm experimenting with a Cloud Endpoint API in Python on App Engine, but I'm having some difficulty getting a simple request parameter.

I'm more familiar with Cloud Endpoints for Java, so I'm possibly (probably) missing something obvious.  All I'm trying to do in this example is return the ServiceInfo object with an `id` specified in the url path, `/services/<id>`

I have a trivial response message class:

```
class ServiceInfo(messages.Message):
    crs = messages.StringField(1)
    services = messages.StringField(2)
```

and API class:

```
@endpoints.api(name='myApi', version='v1', description='My API', audiences=[endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID])
class MyApi(remote.Service):

    #No request body, but need to capture the id from the URL
    ID_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
        message_types.VoidMessage,
        id=messages.StringField(1, variant=messages.Variant.STRING, required=True))

    @endpoints.method(ID_RESOURCE, ServiceInfo, path='services/{id}', http_method='GET', name='station.getServices')
    def get_services(self, request):
        print request.id
        ...
        return ServiceInfo(crs=request.id, services=...)
```

Now, if I make a request through API explorer and enter ABC as the `id` field, I see this request:

`GET /_ah/api/myApi/v1/services/ABC`

But the response says

`"Error parsing ProtoRPC request (Unable to parse request content: Message CombinedContainer is missing required field id)"`

And when I print `request.id`, I get `None`.

All I'm trying to do is get the `id` from the path - am I missing something really obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work with a path ending in `services?id=ABC` instead of `services/ABC`?  The docs seem to say they'd both work but I'd first try that -- and then I'd try renaming the arg from `id` to `foo` just in case you're running into some alas-not-mentioned "reserved name".  Let us know...!

Comment: Interesting!  `services?id=ABC` gives a 404 but `services/?id=ABC` gives me the correct behaviour.  I can say there doesn't seem to be anything special about `id` too.  So now I just need to work out why it doesn't work in the url path. I don't seem to be doing anything different to [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api) example.

Comment: Is it possible for you to link a deployed app that shows this behavior?

Comment: This is actually only running locally but after a couple of days off this project, I restarted the local dev server and it seems to be working, with no code changes.  I'll mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-visiting this after a couple of days, I restarted the local dev server (using `gcloud preview app run ...`) and it seems to now be working with the `id` in the url path (with no code changes) so perhaps the dev server environment had been caching an old version of one of my files?